# Is it a problem if I publish my thesis bearing the same title of a journal article I published previously?

Tags: publications

I have published a research paper based on my masters thesis. The name of the research paper is same as that of my thesis. The copyright to the paper is held by the journal in question. Now I want to publish my thesis in ProQuest. Will I run into trouble for the same name?

Comment: I'd change the thesis title a little...

Comment: I can't change the thesis title since it has already been accepted by my university.

Comment: Can you add "(thesis)" or something at the end of the title?

Comment: I don't think that will be a good idea.

Comment: Well, unfortunate, but not unheard-of. Just today, I saw a (math) thesis and a brief paper in Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. U.S.A., by the same person, with exactly the same title. The PNAS thing was "just" a relatively brief announcement of the results of the thesis, with sketches of proofs. The thesis itself (or any longer version) seems never to have been otherwise published, for what reason I don't know, although the author did publish a few more papers.

Comment: @paul garrett: I too have seen this several times. In fact, *Totally and Partially Ambiguous Points of Planar Functions* is the title of a 5-page announcement (in Volume 2 of **Real Analysis Exchange**), the title of a Ph.D. thesis, and the title of a 24-pages research paper (in Volume 26 of **Zeitschrift für Mathematische Logik und Grundlagen der Mathematik**), all by the same person.

Answer (score 3):

#### No.

Your copyright should not be an issue, provided that you either are the sole owner of the copyright, or that you have provable permission of the owner/contributors to use the same name.

But on that note, names aren't easily copyrighted. There are thousands of papers, books, magazine articles, and other such that include the same kind of name as each other, and I would bet that there are one or two sharing your paper's exact name.

If anything or anyone happens to do research of their own and says anything about it, which I personally doubt will happen, but hey... Just prove that you are the owner of the document, or allowed by other contributors to use it.

Comment: "I would bet that there are dozens [of other papers, book, magazine articles, etc.] sharing your paper's exact name." That seems unbelievably unlikely. The names of papers tend to describe the contents and, while there may be many papers about the same area, it's very unlikely that more than a couple of those would be looking at the same angle of the same precise topic and anything else is very likely to have a different name. I don't think I've _ever_ come across two different papers with the same title. If every title was used by dozens of papers, I'd have seen that all the time.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: "papers about the same area, it's very unlikely that more than a couple of those [could possibly have the same title]" - indeed, and of all papers, those that do look "at the same angle of the same precise topic" should be citing each other, making their authors aware of the other papers and thereby usually causing them to intentionally choose different titles, as well.

Comment: @CalebWoodman Three versions of the same thing by the same person is hardly the same as dozens of papers sharing the exact title of some other paper.